# local hard drive missing after installing ubuntu over win8

Tags: windows-8

recently i installed ubuntu 14.04 over windows 8 [not dual boot]. Previously i had two local drives C and D. But now it seems installing ubuntu has merged my both local drive and i am missing my files from local disk D. Is there any way now to retrieve those files from local disk D ? 
thanks

Comment: Please open a terminal window, type the command `sudo blkid` and post the results in your question (press the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/505308/edit) link to add the information).

Answer (score 0):

Boot your windows 8. Go to control panel search for disk partation. That D drive must be hidden. Or its be unmounted after the install check the partation and give it mount location D:/ and you are done.